# Is there a way to code an app that initiates downtimes on iOS

Tags: swift

I would like to set multiple downtimes in a day on my iPhone but the downtime feature of the iPhone only allows me to set one downtime a day. Is there a way to code an app with swift that would essentially not allow me to use my phone or certain apps on my phone during certain times?

Answer (score 0):

With apps being sandboxed I can't imagine any way to do this with a third-party app.

A potential workaround could be to use a Focus that restricts what apps are available on the home screen, with either an activation time or a shortcut automation, maybe with a downtime alert, to enable it.  It wouldn't prevent access, but it might make you think twice before hunting for that doom-scrolling app.